# Grouping file content based specific field in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, grouping

Input ::

```
A   1
A   4
A   5
B   2
B   3
B   6
C   9
C   8
C   7
```

Output ::

```
A   1
    4
    5
B   2
    3
    6
C   9
    8
    7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight forward using `GNU awk`, replace the duplicated fields in column 1 with an empty field.

```
awk 'seen[$1]++ {$1=""} {printf "%-3s %s\n", $1, $2}' input-file
A   1
    4
    5
B   2
    3
    6
C   9
    8
    7
```